# Maps API that look "fancy"

Tags: google-maps, design

We have been using Google Maps V3 during the development of a web service. We've been struggling with getting the maps integrate good with the design, since the maps look kind of grey. Now when i look at Apple Maps, they look so much nicer (in standard mode that is). The colors are brighter, and the maps doesn't look "grey and boring" like Google Maps do.

My questions are,
1. Is there any way to get Google Maps to look like Apple Maps do?
2. If not, is there any (preferably free) maps we could use that looks something like Apple Maps?

Comment: Could you add a couple of screenshots to illustrate your point?

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for [Google Styled Maps](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html). ([docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling))

Comment: I've had a look at it but i don't feel like i can do so much with it :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Openlayers to get **Apple Map** tiles

http://www.refnum.com/tmp/apple.html

But check the terms and conditions first.

Comment: There are a lot of great OSM tiles out there, don't feel you have to get bogged down with Google's offerings.